# Can you use PowerShell to generate a temp Windows 10 profile?

Tags: windows, powershell, profile

I am writing a script to remove user profiles depending on specific criteria.  What I want to know is if there is a command/script that will generate a dummy profile for me to use for testing my script.  I'm not referring to adding a new user. But to replicate the process of a new user profile creation after they have logged in for the first time.

Comment: 1. I don't think there is such a command. 2. Do you have local or domain profiles?

Comment: Both.  But either would be fine.